# Android Scrollview: How to select the Scrollview to return to?

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I'm working on an android app that's working with Scrollviews. On each scrollview are two buttons, info and gallery. When the gallery button is clicked it takes you to a gallery xml. When the info button is clicked it takes you back to the info page.

The problem is, when the info button is clicked it brings you back to the info page on the first scrollview, even if you are on the third or fourth scrollview.

```
public void onClick(View v) {      
//gallery button clicked, go to gallery screen

setContentView(R.layout.dunnanoirgall);
final Button gallery3 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGallery15);
gallery3.setPressed(true);

//info button
Button infoBtn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInfo15);
infoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            **public void onClick(View v) {      
            //info button clicked, go to info screen
            setContentView(R.layout.islandtours);
            //setScrollView(R.id.scrollView2);**

            }
});
```

What I'm looking for is to get a method setScrollView (shown within the **) that allows me to return to the info page of the scrollview I was on, rather than the first scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

I find your question hard to understand. Do you have several scrollviews in one activity or in different activities ? And why does a click on the info button brings you "back" somewhere ?

Comment: Yes I have several scrollviews in one activity. In reality it's a second info button that brings you back to, hopefully, scrollview2

Answer (score 0):

So let me try and get the info right:

You have 4 different layouts each with a scrollview, and two buttons. One to launch a gallery and another to launch an info page.

Its hard to decipher exactly whats going on, but ill try my best.

From what I see from your code you set the contentview on button push, but you aren't changing the actually text. Your probably not changing your information.